# CoffeeScript compiling express.static __dirname + '/public' wrong

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am pretty new to CoffeeScript. I am trying to create Node.js application using the Express.js framework. And in my express app configuration I have this line of code that is compiling wrong:

```
app.use express.static path + '/public'
```

it is compiling to this:

```
app.use(express["static"](path + '/public'));
```

when I need to be this:

```
app.use(express.static(path + '/public'));
```

Does anyone know why this happening and how to fix this? It is causing my public folder to unaccessible.

I am using CoffeeScript 1.3.1

Comment: What happens if you change your original source line to `app.use(express.static(path + '/public'));`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`static` could be a reserved word in future versions of javascript/ecmascript. Just like `top` now. So using it as a variable name could cause errors somewhere.

That's why coffee is trying to avoid it.

But they are equivalent, so try to find errors somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I guess I am just not normally use to seeing the syntax like that.

Comment: I'm not sure it needs solving, because it's perfectly valid javascript code already.

Answer (score 2):

They're equivalent, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Express framework using 'serve-static' module for export static method:

```
exports.static = require('serve-static');
```

You may try solve your problem like this:

```
app.use '/static', require('serve-static')(__dirname + '/static')
```

or override static method in your module.